# Webservice referencing a class with a property of type Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

in my webservice I'm referencing a dll with a class which holds a property of type `Icon` (among others of type `string` and `DateTime`).
When creating a service reference in my UnitTest-project I get the following error.

Error:

> ISerializable type with data contract
>   name 'Icon' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing'
>   cannot be imported. The data contract
>   namespace cannot be customized for
>   ISerializable types and the generated
>   namespace
>   'KoenHoefman.ExchangeRate.WS.NUnit.QueryService'
>   does not match the required CLR
>   namespace 'System.Drawing'. Check if
>   the required namespace has been mapped
>   to a different data contract namespace
>   and consider mapping it explicitly
>   using the namespaces collection.

I do have access to the source-code of this dll, so it's possible to make some changes, but these changes should be very minimized. The class is marked with the `Serializable` attribute, which probably gives the previous error. When removing this attribute I got another error that stated that I had to mark the class with the DataContractAttribute and the members with the DataMemberAttribute.

Now to me this seems a big change since this class is rarely used in a webservice (just this time). I haven't tried this yet, but I was wondering if there's another solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you create another class to carry the data - this class can wrap around problematic class and expose needed properties - you should annotate this class with DataContractAttribute & DataMemberAttribute - it is always a good idea to explicitly mark your service contract.

As far as icon goes, you need to decide if you must transport/expose icon information via web service. If yes then you could expose a property of type `byte[]` (or base64 encoded string) to transmit the icon data.

Comment: Well, about the Icon exposed: I know it's not quite right, but this way my app holds the same icons as the other apps that are already using this dll. I followed your advise and made myself a wrapper-class with a property byte[] instead of Icon.

Comment: A follow-up question: why is it a  good idea to explicitly mark the service contract? I've never done that before and never ran into any problem. Is there a special reason for that, or just "good practice"? (The latter is reason enough for me to start doing it, but maybe there's another one?)

Comment: @Koan, marking your contract is a opt-in model i.e. each property exposed as a part of contract is a conscious decision on your part. Its quite possible that you may not expose certain properties/members or you can expose certain properties with different name (in data contract)- that would allow you to use same class for implementation and interface/contract. Such scenarios can occur when your services undergo changes and you can still change implementation but keep contract same.